# NodeJS - reading Image Binary File

Tags: node.js, stream, binaryfiles, postman, binary-data

I am working on the API for store a file uploaded by the user.

```
function uploadPhoto(req, res) {
    var imagedata = new Buffer('');

    req.body.on('data', function (chunk) {
        imagedata = Buffer.concat([imagedata, chunk]);
    });
    req.body.on('end', function (chunk) {
        fs.writeFile('success.jpeg', imagedata, 'binary', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        })
    });
}
```

There is an error when I used req.body.on('data').
The data from postman
[image]
[image]

When I print out the value of req.body with console.log("message: "+req.body), it was string and has value:
[image]

I tried to write to file by using Buffer like this

```
var writeFile = function (type, cb) {
    var data = new Buffer(req.body, type);
    fs.writeFile(type + '.jpeg', data, type, function (err) {
        cb(null, data.length);
    });
}
async.parallel([
      writeFile.bind(null, 'binary'),
      writeFile.bind(null, 'utf8'),
      writeFile.bind(null, 'ascii'),
      writeFile.bind(null, 'ucs2'),
      writeFile.bind(null, 'base64')
   ], function (err, results) {
      response.status(200).send({});
   })
```

This will create some jpeg files with different size but can't read them as an image.

How can I store this image from the user?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good case for streams.

```
function uploadPhoto(req, res) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/success.jpeg')
    req.pipe(file).on('error', function(err) { console.log(err) })
}
```

Headers could also help determine what file type and character encoding it has.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/success.jpeg', {defaultEncoding: req.headers.encoding || 'utf8'})
```